# All images are in wrong path console error

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement images through data array while it shows can't find images.

**slide interface**

```
export interface Image {
  title: string;
  url: string;
}
```

**slide.component.ts**

```
  public images = IMAGES;
}


var IMAGES: Image[] = [
  { "title": "We are covered", "url": "../../images/cover1.jpeg" },
  { "title": "Generation Gap", "url": "../../images/cover2.jpeg" },
  { "title": "Potter Me", "url": "../images/cover3.jpeg" },

];
```

**Folder structure**
image
home -> slide -> slide.component.ts
This file is called slide.component.ts and located in the folder called slide and slide folder is located in Home folder.
Outside from Home folder, there is another folder called images. So I assume I described path correctly so what is wrong?

Comment: It needs to be the path relative to the URL, not relative to the file structure. So if your page is `mypage.com/home` and your images are in `mypage.com/images/cover1.jpeg`, you just need `images/cover1.jpg`

Comment: Yes, but what if I don't have that URL? I have those images only on the folder. when I try to use that way that you said it says 404 error. Is there other way to get it from the folder instead of URL?

Comment: Where are your images placed? `assets/images` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all your images to work correctly in all kind of builds and regular serving, you should put them to `src/assets` folder, and finally your path to them should be something like `../assets/image-file.png`. And also don't forget to include these assets to `.angular-cli.json`:

```
"apps": [
  {
    "assets": [
      "assets",
      ...
    ],
    ...
  }
];
```

Comment: like:
{ "title": "Potter Me", "url": "../assets/image-file.png" }, ??

Comment: @Artyom, yes, but don't forget about other steps :)